# Boxfuse AWS default region Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, cloudcaptain

So I have a springboot application that I 'd like to deploy to AWS using boxfuse. 
Deployement onto the AWS Services yields the following error:

```
ERROR: Your AWS account does not have a default VPC in the eu-central-1 region
=> change the AWS region in the Boxfuse console
```

Going to the boxfuse Console:

```
Your AWS account has no default VPC in eu-central-1. Please ask AWS support to recreate it or select a different region
```

Where exactly can I fix this in AWS? How can I change the region for boxfuse / fix this by maybe creating a new VPC ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently the only way to do this is through the AWS Customer Support. Just wanted to mention in Case someone had the same issue.

Comment: You can also select a different AWS default region for your Boxfuse account by clicking the button under the globe on the Overview tab of the Boxfuse Console. Alternatively you can also create a custom Boxfuse environment with a non-default VPC and use that one instead.